# What does output of a hidden layers in ANN mean?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, classification

Say, if we have a binary classification problem, we expect our output to be a single value, but while building ANN we write:
`nn.Linear(4,6) # assuming we are predicting based on the 4 input features nn.linear(6,3) nn.Linear(3,1)`
What does that output features of 6 in first layer or 3 in second layer mean?

I am unable to visualise what's happening in these hidden layers

Answer (score 0):

They are linear combinations of the input.

If you are **not** using a non-linearity, then these hidden layers are effectively pointless. Since the entire network collapses into a single linear regression. You'll also only learn a linear relationship between the input and the output classes.

On the other hand, if you are using non-linearities between layers, then these hidden layers will represent new non-linear combinations of the input features.
These features allow the model to learn different things about the input and then make a final decision about the input and which classes it should belong too.

Initially, we map the 4 inputs into a higher dimension (6), so that we can combine the different parts of the input and learn relationships between them. Then further combining these features allows for learning even more complex non-linear relationships in the next layer. Choosing the size of these hidden layers is its own problem and usually involves some amount of guessing or brute-forcing.

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63152/what-does-the-hidden-layer-in-a-neural-network-compute) is a good answer that talks more about the need for hidden layers.